# How to convert from Option<&T> to &Option<T> in Rust?

Tags: rust, option-type

For a non copy type, like HashMap<String, String> for example, how can I convert from Option<&T> to &Option (without cloning) ? (seems like I am looking for "the opposite" of .as_ref(), but as_deref() is not it)

Comment: There's no way to do so, because it would require moving `T` into an `Option` somewhere. What is your use case?

Comment: `Option<&T>` means *"might contain a reference to a `T`"*. `&Option<T>`, on the other hand, means *"definitely contains a reference to an object that might be a `T`"*. They are just very different things. The first one means, there might be a `T` stored somewhere, and we might have a reference to it. The second one means, there is definitely an `Option<T>` somewhere, that might or might not contain a `T`. You can't convert between the two. Creating the second one must involve an `Option` object and maybe moving `T` into it, as @PitaJ mentioned. You can't move out of a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert from `Option<&T>` to `&Option<T>` because that would mean moving the value out from behind the shared reference `&T`.

Rust's rules prevent that with good reason: there could be multiple shared references to an object, so moving the object would leave the other references dangling.

You can, however, move out of a mutable reference using [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), so you can convert an `Option<&mut T>` to `&Option<T>` like this:

```rust
    let h : HashMap<String,String> = HashMap::new();
    let mut o1 = Some(h);                       // Option<T>
    let o2 = o1.as_mut();                       // Option<&mut T>
    let o3 = &o2.map(std::mem::take);           // &Option<T>
```

Note that `take` replaces the argument with the default value of `T`, so you can only use it if `T` implemented `Default`. Other options are to use [`replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) or [`swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

Comment: Note that moving `T` out of a mutable reference actually resets the original object back to its default state. This might have side effects on other code that also uses the `T` object later. This of course depends on the context.